# Entity Framework design first with npgsql to PostgreSql

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

I need to use .NET framework with PostgreSQL. I have an existing Postgre SQL DB which I need to query for some data.

Since the db is already done and is big, I wanted to use Entity Framework design first.

Problem is that the most famous library for connecting to Postgre with .net is NPGSQL. The database I need to connect to has a SSL client certificate requirement, so every time I do a connection with NPGSQL, I need to specify the client certificates at runtime.

I wonder, is there anyway to connect a ORM like entity framework to get my POCO objects automatically generated? Should I consider other ORM ? NHibernate?

As far as I went, only could make a connectiong using ADO.NET straight objects using the callback for client certificates specificated in NPGSQL website.

Thank you!

Comment: Resolved the problem. Had to used PETAPOCO and make a modification to use the certificate on the template.